# Laravel Eloquent is case sensitive

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I want to check if the inputted data already exists in the database.
I've been trying to input data that already exists (but with different case) to test it.
Here is my query

```
        $existing = AmenityType::all()
        ->where('type', $req->type)
        ->first();
```

but it doesn't return anything even if I did this

```
->where('lower(type)', strtolower($req->type))
```

The database collation is `'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'`

Thank you.

Comment: 0 experience with this language, but you could try replacing `'lower(type)'` with `lower('type')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `all()` already returns you a Collection so the where clause is done on the collection instead on the db.

Try it like this:

```
$binds = array(strtolower($req->type));

$existing = AmenityType::whereRaw('lower(type) = ?'), $binds)->first();

var_dump($existing);
```

Comment: Thank you, but it says, "Method whereRaw does not exist."

Comment: Now it should be work.. The problem is that you called `all()` method before the where clause

Comment: Oh! Thanks for pointing that out. It's working now! Thank you so much